# Meaning of "it's WWIII"

Tags: meaning

[Any time I tell him to do something he doesn't want to, it's World War 3](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RGg6aI79vgIC&pg=PT15&lpg=PT15&dq=%22He%20doesn%27t%20want%20to,%20it%27s%20World%20War%22&source=bl&ots=blTGJMp1rn&sig=0H4w_4XAQX-fy9iVVUl6rZwFhrw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj55LrtnN7JAhUB1B4KHbsCDL0Q6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=%22He%20doesn't%20want%20to%2C%20it's%20World%20War%22&f=false)

Would you please help me to find the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: I suppose either  he makes a very very big fuss when refusing to do sth or he gives over the top excuses to not do it .

Comment: He refers it to world war 3 because he is stubborn to the extent of there always being a fight/argument (war) over what he is being asked to do.

Answer (score 10):

If you are at all familiar with World War I and World War II, you know that they were long, hard, multi-year struggles with many casualties.

The writer of the sentence is saying that asking "him" to do "something that he doesn't want to" marks the start of a new struggle that is so long, drawn-out, and wide-ranging that it makes the writer feel as if they have started a new World War (which would be World War 3, since WW1 and WW2 are already over).